# Pathlib concatenation mutates value unpredictably

Tags: python, pathlib

I have a class that uses some member variables to form strings. In part of the code it does something like this:

```py
print(self.outfolder)
output_location = self.outfolder / f"{workable}_{i}.wav"
print(output_location)
```

The terminal prints this however:

```
/Users/james/Cloud/Projects/ElectroMagnetic/dump/segments
/Users/james/Cloud/Projects/ElectroMagnetic/reaper/highgain_source/bounces/Kindle_04.wav
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this value is mutating in such a way from the concatenation. The path the does get formed looks a lot like a completely different member variable that is stored in the class is being used so its not unrelated, but it is completely unpredictable. I've gone through and print() debugged as much as I can but I am tearing my hair out trying to understand why the path is being concatenated incorrectly.

Any pointers?

Comment: You appear to be printing out two separate values, if you are trying to check whether `self.outfolder` has mutated, try printing that instead of `output_location`.

Comment: My only thought is that the two paths could point to the same place via sym links, and the transformation is due to the final path being canonicalized.  But I assume you'd recognize this and be telling us about that, and it would be strange occurrence anyway, so I expect that's not it.  I might wonder if `workable` included a relative path, but that wouldn't explain it completely either.

Comment: You said this is "part. of the code".  Can you isolate this behavior to a simple script that still exhibits the same strange behavior.  If not, then that might tell you something.

Comment: I managed to find the problem. I believed that workable was a relative path but it was an absolute path. Never assume!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `workable` was an absolute path not a relative path. This made the path joining produce an unexpected result.